# .htaccess : Loads a directory by default

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have to upload a directory by default when someone comes to my static website

this is the structure

under my public_html I have domain folder 'domainname'. In domain folder I've *webfolder/fr/index.html*

I want to load files under webfolder/fr directly. following is my `.htaccess` under the domain name

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webfolder/fr/
RewriteRule (.*) /en/$1 [L]
```

if I remove fr/index.html it loads files under webfolder. If I set

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webfolder/fr/
```

it gives `500 internal error`.

Please help me how can I fix this.

**To Clarify:**

When I open my domain `www.domain.com` I want it to open `www.domain.com/webfolder/fr`

Comment: please elaborate clearly u wanna upload or  load

Comment: when i open my domain  www.domain.com  i want it to open  www.domain.com/webfolder/fr

Answer (score 1):

Please add following two lines to allow a specific file to load just in case there is no default index file setup already

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Note : if you have to load first php index file then you have set like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to redirect your domain from root folder to some other subfolder

try this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /webfolder/fr [L]
```

hope this code will work for you

**optional**:-you can also do this by changing your home directory in cpanel settings